# Merge-Center align different rows and extract data from various columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel tables that look like this:

[image]

I want to develop a macro that would help me achieve an output that would look something like this:

[image]

I am new to VBA and have tried changing column names using some code snippets available online. It worked, and this is what I used:

```
Sub namefixer()
    s = Array("Response", "Factor", "Scaled Estimate")
    Range("A1:C1") = s
End Sub
```

However, I have no idea how I can pull data from other columns and display them as I like in a new excel sheet. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to VBA I suggest you use the macro recorder on 1 group of rows you want to change into the desired view. It records every step you are doing when manually creating the desired result. Then study that and create your final macro based on the recorded macro. That is the best way and fastest way in my honest opinion to get into VBA quickly.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I can now merge and align the data in same columns. However, I am still struggling with combining data from two different columns into one.

Comment: That is just basic excel vba. For more information on how to use excel and VBA, I sugest you look through the documentation and find some helpful video's on youtube.